# Partition of unity. Functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, integer-partitions

Need to find partition of unity in case of oparator $A_{f}(x)=(|x-1|+x)f(x)$. Operator $A \in L_{2}[0,2]$ 
Partition of Unity is set of operators $E_{\lambda}=E((- \infty,\lambda]) $, where $E(\Omega)=\chi_{\Omega}(A)$. $\Omega$ is Borel set, and $\chi$ is characteristic function of there( i mean $\Omega$).I know how to find $E_{\lambda}$ if $\lambda \in \sigma_{cont}(A)$, but in this task $\lambda=1 \in \sigma_{point}(A)$. 
Also I know that if $a<b$,  then $E_{a}\le E_{b}$.
Please, help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you could explain us what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: Also, what do you exactly mean by a partition of unity for the operator and $A\in L_2$?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: You mean $(Af)(x) = (|x-1| + x) f(x)$.  And $A$ is not a member of $L_2[0,2]$, it is an operator on $L_2[0,2]$.
Hint: $E_\lambda$ is the projection on a subspace of $L_2[0,2]$ consisting of functions supported on a certain set related to $\lambda$ and the function $g(x) = |x-1|+x$.

Comment: Thank you/ But I really stupid;) Please, tell me, how to find $E_{1}$